# Python 3 - Why is this variable not defined in this function

Tags: python-3.x

So when I run the script, it keeps saying that 'sales is not defined'. Am I just missing something obvious? I am new to python. To help be more specific, it says the issue us with 'listing(sales, owner)'. I thank anyone who helps me and I hope you have a nice day.

```
def launch():
    sales = [0] * 7
    sales[0] = float(125900)
    sales[1] = float(115000)
    sales[2] = float(105900)
    sales[3] = float(85000)
    sales[4] = float(150000)
    sales[5] = float(155249)
    sales[6] = float(97500)
    owner = [0] * 7
    owner[0] = "Carson"
    owner[1] = "Smith"
    owner[2] = "Jackson"
    owner[3] = "Swanson"
    owner[4] = "Perry"
    owner[5] = "Beufort"
    owner[6] = "Anderson"
    return sales, owner
def listing(sales, owner):
    count = 0
    count2 = 1
    while count < 7:
        print(count2 , "" , ":" , "" , "owner[count]\t" , "$" , "" , format(sales[count],',.2f'))
        count = count + 1
        count2 = count2 + 1
def main():
    print("Welcome to the Botany Bay home sales calculator")
    print("This program will calculate the average selling price of the homes")
    print("sold this past year.  It will then determine how many homes sold")
    print("above the average and how many homes sold below the average.")
        print("=======================================================================")
    print("")
    print("Botany Bay Home Sales")
    print("*********************************")
    listing(sales, owner)

launch()
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Names defined in a function are local to that function and only visible inside them. Calling:

```
listing(sales, owner)
```

in `main` will fail because those names aren't visible outside of `launch`.

You need to grab the returned values for `sales` and `owner` from `launch` and pass them to `main`. Accordingly, it is better to define `main` as accepting two arguments.

```
def main(sales, owner):
    # rest as is
```

Then, pass the values to `main`:

```
sales, owner = launch()
main(sales, owner)
```

Or, since you might not want `sales` and `owner` to be bound here:

```
main(launch())
```

Take not that if you bind the names `sales` and `owner` with:

```
sales, owner = launch()
```

you needn't define `main` with two arguments since the names are bound globally (i.e `listing(sales, owner)` will find them). I really wouldn't suggest doing that though; it's better (and a bit faster) to pass them as args than leave them like that.

Answer (score 0):

`sales` is in the local scope of your `mains` function whithout having been declared in it.
What you could do is modifying you main function to get 2 arguments like this :

```
def main(sales, owner):
    #do your stuff
```

And then use the two objects returned by `launch()` as follows

```
main(*launch())
```

Where the star is used to "unpack" into two objects what is actually returned as only one by `launch()`, i.e. `launch()` returns `(<type 'list'>, <type 'list'>)`, i.e. a tuple containing two objects. `*launch()` returns the unpacked version of this tuple.

So to sum up your entire code would be (tested)

```
def launch():
    sales = [0] * 7
    sales[0] = float(125900)
    sales[1] = float(115000)
    sales[2] = float(105900)
    sales[3] = float(85000)
    sales[4] = float(150000)
    sales[5] = float(155249)
    sales[6] = float(97500)
    owner = [0] * 7
    owner[0] = "Carson"
    owner[1] = "Smith"
    owner[2] = "Jackson"
    owner[3] = "Swanson"
    owner[4] = "Perry"
    owner[5] = "Beufort"
    owner[6] = "Anderson"
    return sales, owner
def listing(sales, owner):
    count = 0
    count2 = 1
    while count < 7:
        print(count2 , "" , ":" , "" , "owner[count]\t" , "$" , "" , format(sales[count],',.2f'))
        count = count + 1
        count2 = count2 + 1
def main(sales, owner):
    print("Welcome to the Botany Bay home sales calculator")
    print("This program will calculate the average selling price of the homes")
    print("sold this past year.  It will then determine how many homes sold")
    print("above the average and how many homes sold below the average.")
    print("=======================================================================")
    print("")
    print("Botany Bay Home Sales")
    print("*********************************")
    listing(sales, owner)


main(*launch())
```